# Display Exceptions of batch Class on vf page

Tags: visualforce, batch, controller, custom-button, error

I have a button on a record, once I click that button it will call a VF page, in that VF page a controller will call a batch class and if we get any exceptions coming from the batch class, I need to display them back to the VF page, otherwise, a successful message should by displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be difficult, if you understand execution of Aysnc apex.

Actually, there can be multiple ways to do this :

1. Using exception handling

If Try catch blocks are implemented for the batch class, you can catch the exception, if anything happens in the execution. Store the error/success in a custom setting record. Implement a Action Poller on your vf page and keep checking on the custom setting records.

2. Using CronJob id

When an user executes the batch in apex, it returns a Cron Trigger job ID, which can be used to track the status of the job.

```
Id cronTriggerId = System.scheduleBatch(parameters,..)
```

Refer CronJob, CronJobDetail and AsyncApexjob objects in Salesforce.